# Find users based on a specific role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I am trying to find all users based on a specific role in my application. I currently have two roles Admin and User. When I try to return a list of users that have a role of "User" with the following linq query:

```
var users = context.Users
                .Where(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains("User")).ToList();
```

it returns 0 users. I have looked at similar questions here but many of them are now outdated. I know that RoleID for example is a hashed key and what I am searching for is plain text "User".

Comment: FWIW, the id is not a "hashed key", but rather a GUID, as a string rather than an actual `Guid`. This was a controversial choice by the Identity team, made for the greatest level of compatibility. You *can* change it to a different type, such as `int`, though. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity. However, none of that meaningfully impacts your question here.

Comment: Always good to learn additional background info, thanks Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RoleId` is not the same as the actual role name string, so that's why you're not getting any matches. The way you need to do this is:

```
var roleId = context.Roles.Where(m => m.Name == "User").Select(m => m.Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then:

```
var users = context.Users
            .Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)).ToList();
```